# distcc issue: does it really speeds up compilation?

Tags: c++, cmake, distcc

I installed distcc and Cmake for a small C++ project. I have two machines: so there is one client where compilation is done locally, and one server, where the compilation is done 'remotely'.

I have followed the instructions to install and configure distcc but I see no improvement when I compile my project, using these simple steps:

```
CXX="distcc g++" cmake my_project && make -j4
```

I have checked everything, on the client and the server machines, and saw no particular behavior. All return codes are 0 (OK) in the logs and there are no error messages. It's like everything is working but with no time gain. I also installed the distccmon-gui tool and checked that both machines are used during compilation time.

Finally, I did try with 4 machines and got the same results, that is, 0 improvement.

The only thing which looks really weird, are the communication times:

```
COMPILE_OK exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:151ms 
COMPILE_OK exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:156ms 
COMPILE_OK exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:182ms 
COMPILE_OK exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:201ms 
COMPILE_OK exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:163ms 
COMPILE_OK exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:202ms
```

Even on the localhost machine, the latency is about 200ms for each performed job.

In the end, there is a little time overhead when i use distcc, which I attribute to communications between the server and the client.

Has anyone already had such an issue with distcc and knows where I should look, or where should I investigate? I'm really stuck on this and believe distcc should bring me additional performance!

Any ideas ? please help :=)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How many cores do you have in total?

Keep in mind that running `make -j4` will use 4 cores in *total*: If there are 4 cores on your local machine and 4 on your server, you must use `make -j8` or you'll have no improvement over just compiling locally.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to set how many jobs the client is allowed to send to any given server.

```
Server/x # where server is the ip and x is the # of jobs
```

If you don't do this is defaults to 4.

Comment: This is an underrated answer! I was having a lot of trouble with only seeing 4 threads out of available 20 on my machine, and didn't see good documentation for the ~/.distcc/hosts file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One issue with distributing builds is how well constructed the make files are.

If your makefile isn't constructed in such a way that it is actually possible to run in parallel, then using distcc probably wont make much difference.

Without distributing the build to another machine, do you get a speed up with -j 4 over no -j option?
 if not, you probably wont see a speed up just from off-loading, unless you are off-loading to a really fast machine, since it is likely only offloading a single job at a time

Comment: hi, unfortunately yes I see a definite improvement when I use parallel Make (-j4 or more) without distcc.

Comment: What is DISTCC_POTENTIAL_HOSTS set to?

Comment: on the client (localhost machine), it is set with the ips of the client and the server. It's something like: `export DISTCC_POTENTIAL_HOSTS='1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8'`, where the first ip is the locahost ip and the second the server ip. I have also set the `--allow` option in the server machine. When I do a `tail -f` of the logs of the client and server, and can see that they both communicate .. but there is no time improvement in the end `:-(`

Comment: You might try using localhost instead of the IP. That should make it use a loopback adapter, rather than going (potentially) all the way out onto the wire and back.

Comment: It goes the same with 127.0.0.1 and/or localhost. Also, I'm using `DISTCC_HOSTS` instead of `DISTCC_POTENTIAL_HOSTS` but it doesn't seem to have any impact. What's strange is the latency on the local host, which is huge .. it's around 200ms in any job summary. Do you know what could cause this ?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Argh .. Thanks anyway